# Generate Test Report with QUnit

Tags: node.js, qunit

I've got a NodeJS application with some QUnit tests. Let's say they look something like this:

*magic.js*:

```js
function doMagic(input) {
    return "Hello " + input + "!";
};
module.exports = doMagic;
```

And *magic-test.js*:

```js
var functionUnderTest = require('./magic.js');

QUnit.test("doMagic()", function(assert) {
    var result = functionUnderTest("World");
    assert.equal(result, "Hello World!");
});
```

Everything works find, tests get run, there are some log messages, only... I'd rather have a nice looking report if possible.

What I tried:

- the [QUnit](https://qunitjs.com/) shows a simple HTML file which imports a test and displays the result; this obviously won't work if it's a NodeJS application
- [qunit-reporter-junit](https://github.com/JamesMGreene/qunit-reporter-junit) generates JUnit reports, which doesn't help me since these are XML files
- QUnit has [callbacks](https://api.qunitjs.com/callbacks/QUnit.testDone) which get run on the end of each test - so I could collect the data I need and generate my own report I guess

Since test reports are a pretty common use case I'm asking the question before reinventing the wheel. Is there already a way to generate QUnit test reports? If so, how?

Comment: Well, if you did keep using JUnit XML you could convert it to HTML. There's a few tools, here's a [really simple one](https://github.com/inorton/junit2html), but if you use Maven (which I'm guessing you're not), you could use [this plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/).

Comment: @jakerella I don't wont to complicate my project with Python dependencies. Nor Maven.